# Advanced filtering in Google Analytics using OR statements

Tags: google-analytics

When generating reports in Google Analytics, a useful feature is the advanced filtering. I'm trying to include two criteria/dimensions for the filter, where they are joined by `OR`.

In other words I would like to filter on **Criteria A** `OR` **Criteria B**. The default and only option in Analytics is `AND`, and there seems to be no way to change this.

Am I missing something? Is there no way to filter with `or`? This seems like a terrible feature flaw in Analytics if so.

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I also couldn't find how to use OR. I can offer you a workaround however. Use the powerful [Matching RegExp](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55582) filter instead of `Containing`.

[image: Google Analytis filter OR clause]

Comment: Thanks for this. It works perfectly. While I'd prefer Google support it out of the box with multiple contains, using the RegEx does work. +1 and answer.

Comment: For me, it only works without a forward slash, i.e. (blog|recent).

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest to understand concepts in RegEx is the pipe. It looks like this: `|`

It’s essentially the word “or” and lets you tell Google Analytics that you want results matching this or that.

Better example: `Mario|Luigi`

http://www.6dglobal.com/blogs/8-simple-yet-powerful-regex-concepts-google-analytics-2012-08-21